# PDO will only return first row of data set

Tags: php, sql, pdo, row

This code displays the first row perfectly but no more. 
I have tried **fetchAll()** , and can get the correct number of rows to display, but only one column is populated per row, and the data values are replaced by the word "Array". I've tried **while** loops. It's driving me mad!

```
/* SQL */
$sql = "SELECT * FROM exam WHERE exam.Level = ? AND exam.Centre!=''";

/* parameter */
$level = 'B2';

/* prepare */
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

/* Execute */
$stmt->execute(array($level));

/* Fetch */
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);      

/* Display */
    echo '<table>
        <tr>';
    if ($row)
      {
        foreach ($row as $key => $value) 
         {
            echo '<td>';
            echo $value;
            echo '</td>';
         }
      }    
     echo '</tr>
         </table>';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing `fetch()` method which is to return only a single row, with `fetchAll()` which returns all the rows. Yet as long as the latter returns a *nested* array, you will need *two* nested `foreach` statements as well.

Besides, it is advised to separate your business logic (or data manipulation) from display logic.
Also, your code contains some unnecessary superfluous stuff which is better to be removed.

So the proper version would be:

```
/* Business logic */
$sql   = "SELECT * FROM exam WHERE Level = ? AND Centre!=''";
$level = 'B2';
$stmt  = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($level));
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);      

/* Display logic */
?>
<table>
<? foreach ($data as $row): ?> 
  <tr>
<?     foreach ($row as $value): ?> 
    <td><?=$value?></td>
<?     endforeach ?> 
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, Thank You YCS! 
Minor edit: each value was being repeated so I just added the `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` parameter to your call to `fetchAll()`.

Comment: @user2304574 you'd rather [set it as a default value](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) once instead of setting it manually with each query

Answer (score 3):

It's because you fetch only one row. You should use fetchAll(); instead of fetch()

change

```
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

to

```
 $row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

or use while loop with fetch(). Morover, if you don't need prepared statements you can use query() and iterate it via foreach()

Comment: I mentioned above that I've tried fetchAll() and a while loop.

Comment: `$row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); ` print_r($row); what does it outputs? Maybe the problem is into your query.

Comment: OK! That prints all my data. So how come it won't come out formatted in a table? When I use fetch() it does, but only the first row, of course.